# Gnuplot 3d plot: How to combine a logscale and linear scale on the same z axis?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

i need to make some 3d plots with a z axis range from 0 to 2.75. to show some details for the data in the lower ranges, i need to make an extra plot using "logscale z 10". now if i could i want to use a z axis with both scales (linear and log 10).

**is there any possibilities that i could have from 0 to 0.09 a linear scale, from 0.1 to 1 a logscale and again from 1 to 2.75 a linear scale?**

on a 2d plot i would just use y1 as linear and y2 as logscale with just two graphs (x1y1 and x1y2) in one plot.

thx

Comment: Please be aware of increasing chances to give you correct and precise answer – share you code, give steps to reproduce or/and test data will increase your chances to get an good answer soon

Comment: You can create three plots and dock them to each other.

Comment: I wouldn't ever do such a scale switching, because you trick those people viewing your plot, even if you try to explain those different scales. And how would you combine the parts at e.g. 0.1, they aren't continuous. Either use linear or log scale, don't mix them. If you need both scales, use two side by side.